# redirecting output from cmd /c

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I have the following command (which I'm running from CScript but testing on the command line).

This command will consciously fail, but I want the output to go to the temp file radA9D4F.tmp

```
cmd /c java -jar "saxon9he.jar" -o:"radF45AB.tmp" -s:"WOnReportTemp_3816933937777_1.xml" -xsl:"filename.xsl1" > radA9D4F.tmp
```

but it simply print the error to the console (correct error but I want it to be redirected)

```
filename.xsl1 does not exist
```

and there is no redirected output in radA9D4F.tmp.

looking at https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html it has a similar example

Spaces in Program Path + parameters with spaces:

```
CMD /k ""c:\batch files\demo.cmd" "Parameter 1 with space" "Parameter2 with space""
```

So I THINK I need to enclose the whole java piece in double quotes somehow like

```
cmd /c ""java -jar "saxon9he.jar" -o:"radF45AB.tmp" -s:"WOnReportTemp_3816933937777_1.xml" -xsl:"filename.xsl1""" > radA9D4F.tmp
```

but this just outputs

The system cannot find the path specified.

in fact even this

```
cmd /c ""java -jar "saxon9he.jar" ""
```

outputs

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So I think the basic issue is how to run a command using cmd /c where potentially all paths may contain spaces

Comment: The standard redirection handle is `1>` _(or `1>>` for append)_, which is often shortened to just `>` _(or `>>`)_. This is for standard output, i.e. StdOut. What you are looking for is error output, (StdErr). The redirection handle for that is `2>` _(or `2>>` for append)_. You therefore need to redirect your StdErr to the same location as your StdOut. You can do that like this, `1>"outputFileOrDevice" 2>"ouputFileOrDevice"`, or more simply either `1>"outputFileOrDevice" 2>&1` or `2>"outputFileOrDevice" 1>&2`. Try therefore `1>"radA9D4F.tmp" 2>&1` or `2>"radA9D4F.tmp" 1>&2`.

Comment: @Compo is right, except that `1>"outputFileOrDevice" 2>"ouputFileOrDevice"` cannot work, unless you specify *different* files, like `1>"anotherOutputFileOrDevice" 2>"ouputFileOrDevice"`…

Comment: @aschipfl, thanks for clarifying, my intention despite having the same name `outputFileOrDevice` was not that both were the same file in that instance, even though I worded and positioned it completely wrong. For the same file I showed the 'more simply' examples.